# Jackson serialize list with polymorphic elements to XML

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a `Zoo` type with a `List<Animal>` field, whose elements are objects of `Animal`'s sub-classes. When I use Jackson to serialize a `Zoo` object to XML, I want to generate different tag names for elements of different types.

For example:

```java
abstract class Animal {}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Dog")
class Dog extends Animal {}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Cat")
class Cat extends Animal {}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Zoo")
public class Zoo {

  @JacksonXmlProperty
  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
  List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Serialize a `Zoo` instance.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
  Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
  zoo.animals.add(new Dog());
  zoo.animals.add(new Cat());
  zoo.animals.add(new Dog());
  String xml = new XmlMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
      .writeValueAsString(zoo);
  System.out.println(xml);
}
```

I expect to get:

```xml
<Zoo>
  <Dog/>
  <Cat/>
  <Dog/>
</Zoo>
```

The actual output:

```xml
<Zoo>
  <animals/>
  <animals/>
  <animals/>
</Zoo>
```

Comment: From what I know it is not possible to obtain what you want unless you write a custom serializer. You can obtain with JsonInfo instead an xml like <Zoo><animal><Dog/></animal></Zoo>, if you think it is useful to you I can submit an answer. –

Comment: @dariosicily Would you please submit an answer about the custom serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to obtain the expected result with a custom serializer, but you loose all the advantages available with the use of [`JsonTypeInfo`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html) and you have to write a custom deserializer too. Anyway, you can define three simple classes like below:

```
public abstract class Animal {}
public class Dog extends Animal {}

@JsonSerialize(using = ZooSerializer.class)
public class Zoo {
  List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Then you have to write your custom `ZooSerializer` serializer that will build your custom xml:

```
public class ZooSerializer extends StdSerializer<Zoo> {

    public ZooSerializer(Class<Zoo> t) {
        super(t);
    }
    
    public ZooSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Zoo zoo, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException {
        jg.writeStartObject();
        for (Animal animal: zoo.animals) {
            jg.writeNullField(animal.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
        jg.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

This will product the expected result at the price of loosing all the advantages due to the automatic serialization and deserialization that could be obtained with `JsonTypeInfo` and [`JsonSubTypes`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSubTypes.html) annotations over the two classes:

```
Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
zoo.animals.add(new Dog());
zoo.animals.add(new Dog());
/* the str content obtained by the serialization of zoo
Zoo>
  <Dog/>
  <Dog/>
</Zoo>
*/
String str = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(zoo);
```